# why I get Syntax error near "else" in assertion in verilog?

Tags: verilog, assert, hdl

I am trying to run a testbench which was written for a neuromorphic chip named ODIN.
Irun this code in Xilinx ISE. I get some errors that do not make sense. here is a part of code:

```
$display("----- Starting verification of programmed SNN parameters");
    assert(snn_0.spi_slave_0.SPI_GATE_ACTIVITY ==  1'b1) else $fatal(0, "SPI_GATE_ACTIVITY parameter not correct.");
    assert(snn_0.spi_slave_0.SPI_OPEN_LOOP              == `SPI_OPEN_LOOP             ) else $fatal(0, "SPI_OPEN_LOOP parameter not correct.");
    assert(snn_0.spi_slave_0.SPI_SYN_SIGN               == `SPI_SYN_SIGN              ) else $fatal(0, "SPI_SYN_SIGN parameter not correct.");
    assert(snn_0.spi_slave_0.SPI_BURST_TIMEREF          == `SPI_BURST_TIMEREF         ) else $fatal(0, "SPI_BURST_TIMEREF parameter not correct.");
    assert(snn_0.spi_slave_0.SPI_OUT_AER_MONITOR_EN     == `SPI_OUT_AER_MONITOR_EN    ) else $fatal(0, "SPI_OUT_AER_MONITOR_EN parameter not correct.");
    assert(snn_0.spi_slave_0.SPI_AER_SRC_CTRL_nNEUR     == `SPI_AER_SRC_CTRL_nNEUR    ) else $fatal(0, "SPI_AER_SRC_CTRL_nNEUR parameter not correct.");
    assert(snn_0.spi_slave_0.SPI_MONITOR_NEUR_ADDR      == `SPI_MONITOR_NEUR_ADDR     ) else $fatal(0, "SPI_MONITOR_NEUR_ADDR parameter not correct.");
    assert(snn_0.spi_slave_0.SPI_MONITOR_SYN_ADDR       == `SPI_MONITOR_SYN_ADDR      ) else $fatal(0, "SPI_MONITOR_SYN_ADDR parameter not correct.");
    assert(snn_0.spi_slave_0.SPI_UPDATE_UNMAPPED_SYN    == `SPI_UPDATE_UNMAPPED_SYN   ) else $fatal(0, "SPI_UPDATE_UNMAPPED_SYN parameter not correct.");
    assert(snn_0.spi_slave_0.SPI_PROPAGATE_UNMAPPED_SYN == `SPI_PROPAGATE_UNMAPPED_SYN) else $fatal(0, "SPI_PROPAGATE_UNMAPPED_SYN parameter not correct.");
    assert(snn_0.spi_slave_0.SPI_SDSP_ON_SYN_STIM       == `SPI_SDSP_ON_SYN_STIM      ) else $fatal(0, "SPI_SDSP_ON_SYN_STIM parameter not correct.");
```

I get this error for each line:

> Syntax error near "else".

Comment: Need switch to tell the tool to use sva syntax?

Comment: I didn't understand your comment

Comment: Some tools need user add something like `-sv` explicitly on the command line to tell the tool there's systemverilog in the design code. I'm not familiar with Xilinx ISE.

Comment: Xilinx ISE doesn't support System verilog language .. Use Vivado tool for ur simulations

Comment: I cant use vivado, is there any way to change the syntax in a way that is appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

In our simple case for simulation with verilog v2k you can use $display to print a message:

```
always @* begin
   $display("----- Starting verification of programmed SNN parameters");
   if(snn_0.spi_slave_0.SPI_GATE_ACTIVITY !=  1'b1) 
      $display("fatal: SPI_GATE_ACTIVITY parameter not correct.");
   ...
end
```

Comment: you mean the line "else $fatal(0, "SPI_OPEN_LOOP parameter not correct.");" is replaceable with: "$display("fatal: SPI_GATE_ACTIVITY parameter not correct.");"??? they do the same thing?

Comment: Assertion prints a message about failure. So does $dislpay in this case. Depending on implementation, assertion might provide more information about failing expression and location of the assertion. You can use ` __ LINE __ or  ` __ FILE __ print location of your $display.

Comment: The first `$display` is not periodically executed.

Comment: right, it will only execute when there is any change in any of signals that you check. This is how the `always` block works.

Answer (score 1):

To sum it up, Xilinx ISE does not support SystemVerilog, so we can not use assertion.
To run this testbench I have to use Xilinx Vivado. Another way is to implement some function equivalent to assertion in verilog. Look at these answers at ["Assert statement in Verilog"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904794/assert-statement-in-verilog#:%7E:text=Verilog%20doesn%27t%20support%20assertions,process%20which%20will%20get%20messy.)